# How to find the cause of filter:notarray error

Tags: angularjs

I am working with a large HTML file including many ng-repeat statements.  Somewhere along the line, I am getting an error like the one below and I cannot figure out how to track down what is causing the issue.  I understand conceptually what the error is complaining about but I do not know what specific variable is responsible.

> angular.js:15570 Error: [filter:notarray] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.9/filter/notarray?p0=%7B%7D
>
> ```
>     at angular.js:99
>     at angular.js:22266
>     at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:16421), <anonymous>:4:303)
>     at d (angular.js:17555)
>     at m.$digest (angular.js:19135)
>     at m.$apply (angular.js:19503)
>     at k (angular.js:13346)
>     at v (angular.js:13603)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.y.onload (angular.js:13508) undefined
> ```

Comment: do you know how many filters you have?

Comment: @Supercool. At least a dozen ng-repeat/filter combos on this one template

Comment: its not a big deal...just search them and see if array is passed to filter.in ng repeat or in case you are using objects to filter then george's answer will help you

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> This error occurs when filter is not used with an array:
>
> ```
> <input ng-model="search">
> <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj | filter:search">
>   {{ key }} : {{ value }}
> </div>
> ```
>
> Filter must be used with an array so a subset of items can be returned. The array can be initialized asynchronously and therefore null or undefined won't throw this error.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Error Reference - filter:notarray
  Not an array](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.9/docs/error/filter/notarray?p0=%7B%7D)

Comment: Right.  So, if you had 3 divs each with an ng-repeat and you get this error, how do you know which div produced it.